# How to remove empty row of NULL fields from mysql query containing sum

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following query which join multiple tables

```
SELECT targa,
registrazioni.turno as turno,
conduttori.nome as nome,
conduttori.cognome as cognome,
spese_importo,risparmio,km, SUM(spese.spese_importo) AS totspese
FROM registrazioni LEFT JOIN conduttori
ON id_conduttore=conduttori.id
LEFT JOIN spese
ON registrazioni.id=spese.id_registrazione
WHERE dataora='$data';
```

when I added this SUM(spese.spese_importo), I started having a small issue, and even if the query shouldn't have for me any matching result, I obtain as result an empty row where every field is NULL.

Of course if I remove that SUM from my query, it does work again and I don't have any rows as result of the query

How could I solve it and check if there are results not null?

I've tried via mysql to add the condition

```
WHERE targa IS NOT NULL
```

(targa is just one field I've randomly choosen between the different fields they are all NULL)

but it didn't clear the row, and via php I was using the condition

```
mysqli_num_rows($result)==0
```

but now that I always have at least 1 row it doesn't work.

any other ideas for checking it before fetching the rows?

Comment: Well.. a simple hack is to check if number of raws is 1 and then check if field is null. Hopefully somebody has a better and more correct solution tho.

Comment: not exactly sure about your scenario but i think using just JOIN instead of INNER JOIN will probably resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp:

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the >right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Does including sum(spese.spese_importo) create a situation where you would get a match on the left side of the join but not on the right side - and have those NULLs?

Comment: you are right, that was the issue. When I wrote again the query in php after testing it, I forgot to make them tables compatible grouping by the results

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to group your results.
Try to add this at the end of your query :

```
GROUP BY registrazioni.id
```

Comment: @Gabz . . . If this solves the problem, consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: I had already accepted another answers that I think it's more useful for similar cases. This worked in my case, but the other one is more general

Comment: This answer is a bit light on details but it solved my issue.  I don't understand why this works - can anyone link to docs or explain?